# Angular2 (click) load dynamically the component view

Tags: angular, dynamic

I've created on click to load a dynamically a component view, but I have each click as separate. I would like to have function, that I pass via the function a string than input that string in my function to load the view.

Here is a working plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXsIWykqKZi5r75VMtw2?p=preview

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Lets dynamically create some components!</h2>
      <button (click)="createHelloWorldComponent()">Create Hello World</button>
      <button (click)="createWorldHelloComponent()">Create World Hello</button>
      <dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData"></dynamic-component>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class App {
  componentData = null;

  createHelloWorldComponent(){

    this.componentData = {
      component: HelloWorldComponent,
      inputs: {
        showNum: 9
      }
    };
  }

  createWorldHelloComponent(){
    this.componentData = {
      component: WorldHelloComponent,
      inputs: {
        showNum: 2
      }
    };
  }
}
```

What would like to have is one function, and from the array define a variable that is passed in the (click) and that load the view.
**Here is a trying   plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/HRKGhCCEfkOhNjXbr6C5?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Lets dynamically create some components!</h2>

          <li *ngFor="let item of myMenu">

              <button (click)="loadView({{ item.viewname }})">{{ item.id }}</button>
         </li>

      <dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData"></dynamic-component>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  componentData = null;
   myMenu = {};
      constructor() {
        this.myMenu = myMenu;

      }

  loadView(viewName){

    this.componentData = {
      component: viewName,
      inputs: {
        showNum: 9
      }
    };
  }


}

const myMenu = [
    {
     id: 1, 
    viewname: 'HelloWorldComponent'
    },
    {
     id: 2, 
     viewname: 'WorldHelloComponent'

    },


];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the below code,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Lets dynamically create some components!</h2>
      <button (click)="createComponent($event)">Create Hello World</button>
      <button (click)="createComponent($event)">Create World Hello</button>
      <dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData"></dynamic-component>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

And the component method will have the following code

```
createComponent(val){
    if(val.srcElement.innerHTML==='Create Hello World')
    {
      this.createHelloWorldComponent()
    }
     if(val.srcElement.innerHTML==='Create World Hello'){
       this.createWorldHelloComponent()
     }
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vfel3xHqMoBh40mmDOFz?p=preview)** updated your plunker.

Update 1: When you are not ready to handle them in the if conditions you should have a mapping property to return the componentData based on the clicked item.

```
var myComponents =[{
        id : 1,
        component: HelloWorldComponent,
        inputs: { showNum: 9 }
    },{
        id : 2,
        component: WorldHelloComponent,
        inputs: { showNum: 0 }
    }];
var myMenu =    [{
    id: 1, 
    viewname: 'HelloWorldComponent',
    componentID : 1
    },
    {
     id: 2, 
     viewname: 'WorldHelloComponent',
     componentID : 2
    }];
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/v6bCOUVaVm1JAAXZmVzT?p=preview)**

Comment: You are passing an event and than reading the innehr HTML, but I would like to instead of passing Event is to insert from an array data and pass that to the function. The button inner HTMl will be total different. So I can use your example.  Also doing with the if statements as you have in the end I will  end up with 1000 if statements. :(

Comment: update the above comment by looking for spell check and meaningful sentence.

Comment: Comment updated, but did u see my plunker with an array?
http://plnkr.co/edit/HRKGhCCEfkOhNjXbr6C5?p=preview

Comment: you should be using a property in the json array to point to specific component data. will update the plunker in a minute and tell

Comment: Hurray, you done it! Amazing. So you pass the item inside the click function, and than using _.find  to link it to myComponents...

Comment: your wish you can pass the entire item or just the id and bind it in the function

Comment: So in the myMenu, do i need the viewname? as now I am linking it to myComponents?

Comment: its your wish if you want keep else remove. So was the answer helpful?? any more help you neeed

Comment: answear was helpfull in the sence you pointed me the right direction and helped massively, but can't seem to understand the function you got with 
 _.find. As I was thinking of the code like something like this  loadView({{item.id}}) but you got it loadView(item). I planning to have a nested array, and thinking on how this function will work on the nested array. I am preparing the plunker.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/eLWy6jzkODOjEY64Reyh
See what I mean, the function is perfect for main menu, with ID 1, but if you click on ID 2, it does not right, as I can't seem to understand how you did in your function

Comment: You used yurzi code in the previous post so it didnt work. use my code and updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S6pW5M0GkgDGieSi9KHE?p=preview)

Comment: Also did you setup anything specific because when I copy changes to my local i get an error:  Cannot find name '_'.)

Comment: I used lodash library. Mark both of my answers and upvote too :) as both helped you. are you there?

Comment: I can't upvote as I haven't got enough raitings, as soon as I reach my profile status to 50 I will upvote this one.

Comment: mark both answers you will get 4 points and u need only one more point to upvote

Comment: Aravind, can you msg to my email? chris.tarasovs(at)gmail.com
I seen you are on freelance but can't seem to find an email to get intouch.

Comment: @Aravind i have loaded the components dynamically. And i need to create back button event can you suggest.

Comment: have a look at this [**medium blog**](https://medium.com/@aravindfz/load-modal-component-dynamically-in-angular-5fda8e1dc3e7)